# SSRS report need to show n-time based on dataset rows

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

I have designed two pages and each page have different table.Currently my dataset return only one user details.So i have bind all details in table.

**Requirement**
 
In case data set return two user details ,need to print two user details.First two pages for first user and second two page for second user.

Is this possible in SSRS report? If yes please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have a report working for a single user then I would normally do this with subreports.

Asumming your current report accepts a userid or similar as a parameter....

Create a new new report.
Add a dataset that returns a list of users that you want to produce the report for
Add a table and set its dataset property to the name of the dataset you just created.
You can remove the header row and all columns except one from the table
In the remaining cell, right-click and choose "insert Subreport"
Right-click the subreport placeholder and choose properties
Choose your original report as the subreport
Click the parameters tab and choose the subreport property name on the left side, choose the field from your dataset that contains the userid (or whatever value you pass as a parameter) on the right side.

That's pretty much it, when you run the new report, it will produce 1 row per user, in each row it will run your subreport.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a matrix, specifically row groups, grouping by using user details, and possible inserting a page break between each instance. This should get you going in the right direction.